# Why does ―・appear on Japanese dictionary?

Tags: words, usage, kanji, etymology

For example this definition of 臨む: 風景・場所などを目の前にする。向かい対する。面する。「海に―・んだ部屋」
Why does ―・appear instead of the word itself? What's the reason behind it, how do I call it and why that only exist in a Japanese dictionary?

Comment: As for the name, it's a symbol called ダッシュ followed by a symbol called 中点 or 中黒. I don't think there is a dedicated name for this combination. For words that does not conjugate (e.g., nouns), only ダッシュ is used.